# What is the disadvantage of octomap 3d map?

Tags: octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, anybody knows the disadvantage of the 3d structure produce by octomap?

I know the advantages are:

1. Probabilistic representation
2. Memory-efficient
3. Flexible, multi-resolution

Any disadvantages?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216063/what-is-the-disadvantage-of-octomap-3d-map?/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Octomap is a compact way to encode the environment about obstacles and even colors. These maps are very useful for self-localization, although not so much to navigate when the robot is on the ground and there are no obstacles in height that prevent the robot from passing through.**

*Source:

J. Ginés, F. Martín, V. Matellán, F. J. Lera, and J. Balsa, “Dynamics maps for long-term autonomy,” in 2017 IEEE International Conference on Autonomous Robot Systems and Competitions (ICARSC), Apr. 2017, pp. 85–90, doi: 10.1109/ICARSC.2017.7964057.*

---

Originally posted by [EkanshSharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/50347/ekanshsharma/) with karma: 26 on 2021-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1